# get notification when permissions change in metro app

Tags: c#, geolocation, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm working at a Win 8 Metro App with c#.

in my App I use the geolocation Service to get the current coordinates of the users position. The first time you start the App you'll be asked for the permissions.
This all works fine and I get the coordinates without a problem.

Now I want to give the user a message as soon as the permissions changes.
How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh465148

**Provide UI for reenabling location services**

Have your app provide UI for reenabling location services—for example, a refresh button that reinstantiates the Geolocator object and tries to get location info again.

- **If the user reenables location access after disabling it, there is no notification to the app**. The status property does not change and there is no statusChanged event. Your app should create a new Geolocator object and call getGeopositionAsync to try to get updated location data, or subscribe again to positionChanged events. If the status then indicates that location has been reenabled, clear any UI by which your app previously notified the user that location services were disabled, and respond appropriately to the new status.
- **Your app should also try again to get location data upon activation**, or when the user explicitly tries to use functionality that requires location info, or at any other scenario-appropriate time.

Answer (score 1):

The StatusChanged event can be used for this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.statuschangedeventargs.status.aspx

```
case Windows.Devices.Geolocation.PositionStatus.disabled:
     // The app doesn't have permission to access location,
     // either because location has been turned off.
     return "Your location is currently turned off. " +
         "Change your settings through the Settings charm " +
         " to turn it back on.";
     break;
```

Comment: hmm this almost works, but the StatusChanged-event is only called when I turn the permissions off and not when I turn them on afterwards...